# How do I create text with a sense of depth?

Tags: text, depth

I like the appearance on a button used by [this site](http://www.searchfreefonts.com/font/revue.htm).  Here is an example:

[image]

Is this effect achieved graphically or are there fonts available?  If there are fonts like this, what search terms should I use to find them?

What are the tips & tricks for creating objects with a similar sense of depth?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to clarify what a "depth perception" font is, or show an example.

Comment: See text "Download" on top-right of this website. http://www.searchfreefonts.com/font/revue.htm   It has a feeling of depth.

Comment: "Where can I search them?" I'd start with Google.

Comment: That's not a "depth perception" font.. That's an image effect which can be applied to any font.

Comment: The style is called "letterpressed" or just "letterpress" - use "letterpressed font photoshop" if you want to google for more info. But Scott's excellent answer tells you all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Photoshop, you can create this sense of depth easily with a drop shadow and inner shadow.

[image: drop shadow]
[image: inner shadow]

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment above (please edit the original question rather than a comment, as it makes it easier for us to answer) I think you are simply asking where you can find fonts with built in 3-D looks.

For the record, your example link likely wasn't a font with that effect, but, rather, it was a font set in PhotoShop (or the like) and then various bevel/emboss/shadow/gradient effects were used to emulate the particular 3D effect they were after.

If you want a font with that effect already designed into the font, simply search for fonts with particular keywords such as '3d'. Example:

http://www.myfonts.com/search/3d/fonts/